# Picasa API image URL extraction

Tags: picasa, google-api-python-client

I have been able to programmatically create an album however, using the Picasa Python API I want to achieve two more tasks.

1. Uploading an image to the album. (Although I am following instructions I seem to be missing out on something)
2. Extracting the URL of the uploaded image and using this on my Google Site in the "img" tag.

An example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the examples in the extended documentation?

For example, [check this out](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/).

Where you can find a link to `examples` and `sample code` at the bottom.